# Minimizing a sum of the form $\sum |b_i-a_{ii}|$ over all matrices of rank $\leq k$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $r>k$ be natural numbers. Let $b_1 \geq ... \geq b_r \geq 0$ be some real numbers.

I consider the sum $|b_1-a_{11}|+...+|b_r-a_{rr}|+\sum_{i=r}^n |a_{ii}|$ where $A$ is a real square matrix of rank $\leq k$. I want to know if this sum is minimal when we take $A=\text{diag}(b_1,...,b_k,0...,0)$, the diagonal matrix whose first $k$ values on the diagonal are $b_1,...,b_k$ and the others are zero.

If the matrix $A$ has at most $k$ nonzero rows (which in general does not hold) then this is clear because there can be at most k nonzero values on the diagonal, so the sum is at least the sum of all terms $|b_i|=b_i$ which we did not make zero, which is at least the sum of the smallest $b_i$, which we achieve in the particular matrix described above. What happens in general?